# How do I run a more efficient program in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very time consuming program that uses pandas. Luckily it just spits out information and doesn't effect any user experience. That being said, it is a real pain to debug and re-run all the time.

I understand that the nested for loop is probably causing most of the performance drag, but that is unavoidable due to me needing every possile permutation. What I'm looking for are any other ways to squeeze some better performance out of my program. For instance, are there more efficient pandas/datframe idioms that I can be using instead?

The program looks something like this:

```
dict = {} 
   for w_id in range(1,6):
        for x_id in range(1,26):
            for y_id in range(1,12):
                for z_id in range(1,6):


                    #create a query based on id's and assign it to, lets say df1
                    #assign a special combo of id's as df1's index
                    dict[row_id] = df

df_foo = pd.concat(dict)
```

`df_foo = df_foo.groupby(level = 0).describe().to_csv`

Comment: There are definitely some things that can be done to help.  Unfortunately, you've given us so little to go on, it's difficult to say anything concrete.  Most people (I think), at least I don't want to waste my time giving vague advice that may not be what you want and isn't helpful to anyone else either.  Moral is, spend more time developing this question.  Edit it with more detail.  In fact, read [**this:MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**this:HowToAsk**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion. I personally thought that making it more general as opposed to pasting my entire source would​ make a better format.

Comment: Your sentiment is appreciated.  You are correct that we don't want to see your entire source :-)  Reading MCVE will be enlightening though.

Comment: Internally Pandas uses numpy arrays, using `df.values` you can directly access them, and iterating over them directly is faster than using pandas' builtin iterators. Also you can try to use numpy broadcasting.

Comment: As others mentioned, your question is too vague..without further context, I'd suggest taking a look at itertools.product, which can create all possible permutations without using the for loop

Comment: @user3582076 the for loop isn't to create all permutations, that's trivial. The for loop is there to perform pandas operations on every set.